# A-Frame buttons of toggle menu is not working

Tags: html, toggle, aframe, togglebutton

The toggle menu is not working right. it is working in some cases for example "menu two" is working fine. I did, I think, the exact same in the other menus, but there the buttons are not working. in menu three, four, and six I can enter but I can not use any further buttons.

I really don't understand the problem. Does someone see my mistake? I would be so happy. All the best, and thank you.

I uploaded the index in WeTransfer because it's difficult to which part of the code is the issue, see image.

[image: link preview]

Answer (score 0):

When I run the file I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null
> index.html:28

Thats this line:

```
28 | var menuItems = menu.querySelectorAll(".clickable");
```

That would mean the "menu" is null. In your code:

```
26 | var menu = this.data;
```

That would also mean this code won't work (probably not even attempt to because there was an error above)

```
66 |

for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
    // classList.replace() is not currently supported in Microsoft Edge and Samsung Internet.
    // menuItems[i].classList.replace('clickable-disabled', 'clickable');
    // Workaround
    menuItems[i].classList.remove("clickable-disabled");
    menuItems[i].classList.add("clickable");
}

72 |
```

I don't know what element throw error but I hope this will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. Actually the problem was that I had do define the buttons with a-plane and not a-entity. So I figured that out. But the performance is really bad, I changed the cursor, so the cursor is the mouse and its really working very badly. do u know how I can improve the performance?

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("toggle-menu", {
       dependencies: ["raycaster"],
       schema: {
         type: "selector"
       },
       // menu.object3D.visible doesn't show correct value when init() is used, possibly due to load order. Use play() instead.
       play: function() {
         var button = this.el;
         var scene = this.el.sceneEl;
         var cursor = scene.querySelector("[raycaster]");
         var menu = this.data;
         var menus = scene.querySelectorAll(".menu");
         var menuItems = menu.querySelectorAll(".clickable");
         // Replace .clickable with .clickable-disabled for our menu if it's hidden and refresh raycaster.
         if (!menu.object3D.visible) {
           for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
             // classList.replace() is not currently supported in Microsoft Edge and Samsung Internet
             // menuItems[i].classList.replace('clickable', 'clickable-disabled');
             // Workaround
             menuItems[i].classList.remove("clickable");
             menuItems[i].classList.add("clickable-disabled");
           }
           // Refresh raycaster.
           cursor.components.raycaster.refreshObjects();
         }
         // Define handler function for event listener.
         function clickHandler(e) {
           // If our menu is already visible, return and exit function.
           if (!!menu.object3D.visible) return;
           // Hide all menus.
           for (var i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
             // If menu is our menu, skip to next menu in the loop.
             if (menus[i] === menu) continue;
             // Get each menu's items.
             var items = menus[i].querySelectorAll(".clickable");
             // Hide each menu.
             menus[i].object3D.visible = false;
             // Disable each menu's items by temporarily removing class.
             for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
               // Replace class.
               // classList.replace() is not currently supported in Microsoft Edge and Samsung Internet.
               // items[j].classList.replace('clickable', 'clickable-disabled');
               // Workaround
               items[j].classList.remove("clickable");
               items[j].classList.add("clickable-disabled");
             }
           }
           // Only show our menu.
           menu.object3D.visible = true;
           // Make our menu's items clickable.
           for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
             // classList.replace() is not currently supported in Microsoft Edge and Samsung Internet.
             // menuItems[i].classList.replace('clickable-disabled', 'clickable');
             // Workaround
             menuItems[i].classList.remove("clickable-disabled");
             menuItems[i].classList.add("clickable");
           }
           // Refresh raycaster objects.
           cursor.components.raycaster.refreshObjects();
         }
         // Add event listener to the button.
         button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
       }
     });
```

and: `<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse; fuse: false" raycaster="objects: .clickable" opacity="1">`